# JavaScript Switch statement is not returning the correct value

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, quasar-framework

For this switch function:

```
import { Screen } from 'quasar'

export const setZoomLevel = (distance) => {
  const dist = parseInt(distance)
  switch (Screen) {
    case Screen.lg && dist >= 50:
    case Screen.md && dist >= 25:
    case Screen.sm && dist >= 10 && dist <= 20:
    case Screen.xs && dist >= 10 && dist <= 30: return 8
    case Screen.sm && dist >= 25:
    case Screen.xs && dist >= 40: return 7
    default: return 9
  }
}
```

If the screen is extra small (xs) and the distance is 50, it should return 7.  However, it always returns 9.  If I `console.log(Screen.xs && dist >= 40)` the result is `true`, but it never selects that case, it always returns the default.

Comment: `Screen.lg && dist >= 50` is a boolean. You are comparing Screen to a boolean, it can never match and will always return the default.

Comment: That is not how a `switch` statement is supposed to be used; the syntax for a `switch` statement is `switch ([expression]) { case [value1]: ... }` (see [details on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch)). You can "twist" it to work as you expect but twisting syntax use is never a good idea. There is no shame in using `if ... else if ... else` so why not going with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of comparing `Screen` to boolean value, which caused your unexpected result, you should do the trick of comparing true to true by using `switch(true)` instead

```js
const dist = 50;
const Screen = { xs: true };

const f = () => {
  console.log(Screen.xs && dist >= 40);
  switch (true) {
    case Screen.lg && dist >= 50:
    case Screen.md && dist >= 25:
    case Screen.sm && dist >= 10 && dist <= 20:
    case Screen.xs && dist >= 10 && dist <= 30:
      return 8;
    case Screen.sm && dist >= 25:
    case Screen.xs && dist >= 40:
      return 7;
    default:
      return 9;
  }
};

console.log(f());
```

Comment: My implementation was essentially saying ```if (Screen.xs && dist ≥ 40 === Screen)``` instead of ```if (Screen.xs && dist ≥ 40 === true)```, which would never work.  Thank you for the clarification!  This may not be what switch was intended for, but IMHO it reads a lot better than a bunch of nested if-then statements.